# Gradle multi-build flat independent projects using BND tools

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, multi-project, bnd

I would like to have a multi-project build in a structure as such

```
common
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    build
         common-build.gradle



proj1
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
proj2
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
...
projn
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Each project including the common project can be built independently, and each project has its own build, properties, and settings gradle files. The build.gradle files in the projects all import a task from common-build.gradle within the common project. The build.gradle and settings.gradle is a default one outputted by bndtools from eclipse which sets up the bndtools gradle plugin for the bundles within each project.

All is well, but there is no convenient way for me to build all the projects in one go. All projects are dependent on common, but none are dependent on each other, therefore if common is built, all the others can be built in parallel. I would like to solve this using gradle, currently I can accomplish somewhat desirable results using a bash script but I cannot really leverage parallel builds since each build has to start its own daemon. That means there will be n + 1 daemons initialized for a build. Any guidance would be appreciated!